# Executing test by @Tag annotation in Junit5 will not work after removing 'junit-platform-surefire-provider'

Tags: maven, tags, junit5

I very often use `@Tag` annotation in my tests because it is easy to run exactly tagged tests from terminal.

For example:

```
    @Tag("api_t1")
    @Test
public void api_Test() {
    someTest_Here();
```

Then I can run from terminal exactly this (or these) tests by command:

```
mvn test -Dtag=api_t1
```

But I have started to see WARNING in  console:

```
| WARNING:                                                                      |
 | The junit-platform-surefire-provider has been deprecated and is scheduled to  |
 | be removed in JUnit Platform 1.4. Please use the built-in support in Maven    |
 | Surefire >= 2.22.0 instead.                                                   |
 | » https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven |
```

Ok, I decided to follow this manual and started to change my pom.xml:

1. Change version from 1.3.0 to 1.4.0

   org.junit.platform
   junit-platform-surefire-provider
   1.3.0

**Result**: run tests by tags does not work, will be running all tests from project

```
mvn test -Dtag=api_t1
```

2. Removed this dependency

**Result**: run tests by tags does not work, will be running all tests from project

```
mvn test -Dtag=api_t1
```

---

So, my question - is it possible to do not see this warning message in console OR I should do not touch my plugin version in pom.xml? Or there is another solution which I could not get from [Junit 5 User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding to examples here https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/master/junit5-migration-maven I found solution:

Should be used

`<groups>${tag}</groups>`

Instead of

`<includeTags>${tag}</includeTags>`